# Firebase cloud functions catch/handle error

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, google-cloud-functions

Update Question: error: TypeError: res.json is not a function

I use Firebase Cloud Functions with Express app. I use middleware for handle error, but it is not working. How to catch/handle error when using `throw new Error()`?

My code below:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    throw new Error('this is error')
})

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    res.json({error: err.message}) // error here
}
app.use(errorHandler)

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Please help me. Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you share what documentation you used for the code and how you are planning to implement the error catcher?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. You need a try/catch to capture the error and then use the next function to pass it down the middleware chain.

```js
app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        throw new Error('this is error')
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
})

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    res.json({error: err.message}) // error here
}
app.use(errorHandler)

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Wrap the whole handler in the try block and it will always pass it down to the error handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/catch to handle error like this:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
 try {
      // Your Code
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("error: ", e);
      res.status(500).send(e.message);
    }    
})
```

Comment: I want to handle errors in one common place, because I have many functions. With Express app only, it work well. With express app only, it work well.